# How to get a factor level for unique ID's

Tags: r

Here's a subset of my data.

```
     ID Direction
100 30761     River
101 30762    Marine
102 30763    Marine
103 30764    Marine
104 30765     River
105 30765     River
106 30766    Marine
107 30766     River
108 30767     River
109 30767     River
110 30768     River
111 30768     River
112 30769     River
113 30769     River
114 30770     River
115 30771     River
116 30772     River
117 30772     River
118 30773     River
119 30773     River
120 30774     River
```

What I'm trying to do is get a DF with the same columns except there is only one row for each ID. For example, instead of two rows of data for both ID 30767 and 30768, have one row like this:

```
30767   River
30768   River
```

However, ID 30766 has different values of direction for each row (Marine and River). For this ID, I'd like to do the same as above, but instead, create a new level for the Direction column called 'Both'

```
30766   Both
```

Desired DF looks like this:

```
ID      Direction
30761   River
30762   Marine
...     ...
30765   River
30766   Both
30767   River
...     ...
30773   River
30774   River
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` package, You can use `distinct` function to get all distinct rows first, then count for each ID and mutate the value of the column Direction if the count is equal to 2. Finally, you can select only ID and Direction columns and apply again `distinct`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  distinct() %>%
  mutate(Count = n()) %>% 
  mutate(Direction = ifelse(Count == 2,"Both",Direction)) %>%
  select(ID, Direction) %>% 
  distinct()

# A tibble: 14 x 2
# Groups:   ID [14]
      ID Direction
   <int> <chr>    
 1 30761 River    
 2 30762 Marine   
 3 30763 Marine   
 4 30764 Marine   
 5 30765 River    
 6 30766 Both     
 7 30767 River    
 8 30768 River    
 9 30769 River    
10 30770 River    
11 30771 River    
12 30772 River    
13 30773 River    
14 30774 River
```

**EDIT: Simplification based on @tmfmnk's comment**

As suggested by @tmfmnk in comments, you can simplify my answer and get the same result by doing:

```r
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Direction = ifelse(n_distinct(Direction) > 1, "Both", Direction)) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

Comment: You can simplify it to `df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(Direction = ifelse(n_distinct(Direction) > 1, "Both", Direction)) %>%
 slice(1)`.

Comment: Thanks ! That's really nice way to do it. I will add it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

May be we can get the `unique` rows first and then create a condition to check the frequency of unique elements by each 'ID' and change those having greater than 1 to 'Both, get the `unique` rows again

```
df2 <- unique(df1)
i1 <- with(df2, ave(Direction, ID, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 2)
df2$Direction[i1] <- 'Both'
out <- unique(df2)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(30761L, 30762L, 30763L, 30764L, 30765L, 
30765L, 30766L, 30766L, 30767L, 30767L, 30768L, 30768L, 30769L, 
30769L, 30770L, 30771L, 30772L, 30772L, 30773L, 30773L, 30774L
), Direction = c("River", "Marine", "Marine", "Marine", "River", 
"River", "Marine", "River", "River", "River", "River", "River", 
"River", "River", "River", "River", "River", "River", "River", 
"River", "River")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table) 
setDT(df)
df <- unique(df) 
df[, Direction := ifelse(.N == 2, "Both", Direction), by = ID]
unique(df)

#     ID Direction
#1:  30761    River
#2:  30762    Marine
#3:  30763    Marine
#4:  30764    Marine
#5:  30765    River
#6:  30766    Both
#7:  30767    River
#8:  30768    River
#9:  30769    River
#10: 30770    River
#11: 30771    River
#12: 30772    River
#13: 30773    River
#14: 30774    River
```

## data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(30761L, 30762L, 30763L, 30764L, 30765L, 
                              30765L, 30766L, 30766L, 30767L, 30767L, 30768L, 30768L, 30769L, 
                              30769L, 30770L, 30771L, 30772L, 30772L, 30773L, 30773L, 30774L
 ), Direction = c("River", "Marine", "Marine", "Marine", "River", 
                  "River", "Marine", "River", "River", "River", "River", "River", 
                  "River", "River", "River", "River", "River", "River", "River", 
                  "River", "River")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("100", 
                                                                          "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
                                                                          "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
                                                                          "119", "120"))
```